# "billing music to fashion" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Hockney](https://www.google.jo/amp/s/subsaga.com/bbc/films/arts/2015/hockney.amp.html)

I've heard this sentence in a movie, actually a documentary, and the person says:

> "In fact, his shows were quite unique,and he'd bill the music to the fashion models, to the whole catwalk experience."

I'm not sure about the meaning of "he'd bill the music to the fashion models".

Does it mean that he was the first one that used music in a fashion show?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. Are you sure you heard correctly?

Comment: Are you certain it wasn't 'build'?

Comment: I put an answer to the question, you can look at it @ColinFine

Comment: I believe it is another way of saying "it fits the bill", that is, it is quite  suitable, it is a perfect match. He would make sure the music *matched* the models and the catwalk experience. A variant of "fits the bill" is "fits the ticket".

Comment: I suspect that the documentary speaker has misused the word, "Bill" and should have used, "Tailor" meaning that personalised music was used for each catwalk model rather than the same music used for all.

Answer (score 0):

[THE SOURCE](https://www.google.jo/amp/s/subsaga.com/bbc/films/arts/2015/hockney.amp.html)  0:51:45

[bill](https://www.google.jo/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/bill)

> verb [usually passive]
>   If someone is billed to appear in a particular show, it has been advertised that they are going to be in it.
>   She was billed to play the Red Queen in Snow White. [be VERB-ed to-infinitive]

It means: that he would present/ advertise the music at the fashion model-show.

Comment: You may be right, but it still doesn't make any sense at all to me. I don't see that that meaning fits the context in the slightest. First, this is very rare in the active. Secondly, the original quote doesn't say "he'd bill the music to appear in the show" or even "he'd bill the music to the show" (which I would find odd, but just about comprehensible). It says "he'd bill the music to the fashion models". I can't find any way in which this sense can apply.